# No Suitable application record were found. When Validating Application

Tags: xcode

Okay I register my application to Itunes connect. I make sure that the correct application name and bundle is available.

Then I archieve my project and then I want to validate.

Then I got this message.

What is exactly wrong?

Is apple cannot figure out any application with the same bundle id and the same application name? Which one mismatch?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a common error. Just make sure that you set your app's state to **waiting for upload**

From Apple's documentation:

> Troubleshooting: If Xcode doesn’t find an iTunes Connect application
>   record for your application, the “No suitable application records were
>   found” dialog appears. This dialog also appears when the application
>   record state is not at least Waiting for Upload.

When you register your app, it becomes 'Ready For Upload' first. You have to put it to 'Waiting For Upload' manually, by clicking the bottom-right button in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 3):

I'll add another answer because I just spent the last 30 minutes trying to figure out why I could not get validation to work...

If you have multiple iTunes Connect accounts, make sure you are logging in with the correct account that you created the app in iTunesConnect with.

It sounds like a no-brainer but the Organizer remembers the credentials that you last validated with for deployment. The last app I shipped was several months ago under my contractor credentials. My new app is under my own credentials but I was trying to authenticate with the saved contractor credentials. ugh.

Comment: This may have lead me in the right direction, so I thank you. Unfortunately I enrolled my ios dev account with the same email as my previous account... and I have a feeling everything is fu-barred because of that.

Comment: This answer also helped me, because it turned out I had unintentionally registered the app on a different account with the "limited access" setting, but the iTunes account I use normally was not in that limited access group. I was able to fix this by logging into https://developer.apple.com with the other account, navigating to My Apps / App Store / App Information and changing the access setting in the "Additional Information" section.